# how to pop(delete) values randomly using Jquery

Tags: jquery

*i am having the code like*

```
<input type="checkbox" class="selectionne" id="first" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="selectionne" id="second" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectionne" id="second" value="3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="selectionne" id="second" value="4">
            <input type="checkbox" class="selectionne" id="second" value="5">
                <input type="checkbox" class="selectionne" id="second" value="6">
```

**jquery**

```
var elems = [];
$('.selectionne').change(function(){
  this.checked ? elems.push($(this).val()) : elems.pop($(this).val());
  alert(elems);
});
```

Actually am pushing values to var elems by ckecking the checkboxes.pushing happening properly,
But poping is happening like how i pushed values like 1,2,3,4,5 in reverse order its poping.
i dont want like that, if i check randomly also it has to pop randomly only..

[check here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2UjW/) its working like wat i was explained. i want to pop randomly after unchecking check boxes....

plz help me out..
thanks in advance...

Comment: **Note** IDs must be unique

Answer (score 1):

`pop` always removes the last element, it's the opposite of `push`. If you want to remove a specific element by value, use:

```
function removeValue(array, value) {
    array.splice(array.indexOf(value), 1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var elems = [];
$('.selectionne').change(function(){
if(this.checked){
    elems.push(this.id) 
}
else {
    var toBeDeleted=this.id;  
    elems = jQuery.grep(elems, function(value) {
    return value != toBeDeleted; 
    });
    alert(elems);
}


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XBe89/

Hope this helps